# Rank only on specific set of data values

Tags: sas

How do I rank my data based on only a specific set of value in category? Say if there are category 2, 4, and 5 based on same client/date, then 5 should trump 4 and 2, 4 should trump 2, 5 should trump 2, etc. Other than that, any other category should always rank it as 1. (for sake of simplicity, values have been modified). So, any category of (2/4/5), check trumping logic. Any other category, rank it as 1. Please see below for desired results. Thanks!

want

```
ClientName  Date      Category  Age  rank
A           1/1/2018  1         25    1
A           1/1/2018  2         25    3
A           1/1/2018  3         25    1
A           1/1/2018  4         25    2
A           1/1/2018  5         25    1
A           2/1/2018  2         25    1
B           3/1/2018  1         26    1
B           3/1/2018  3         26    1
```

I tried

```
proc rank data=test out=test2 ties=low descending;
  by clientname date;
   var category;
   ranks rank;
run;
```

Comment: Sounds like you're just looking for the max category per client/date? Is that correct?

Comment: @Reeza in some way yes. I added an additional row of data. For client B, say it has category 1 and 3, it doesn't fall under the hierarchical logic (2/4/5), then I would want to rank it as 1 for both as well.

Comment: So the hierarchy is 5/4/2 if those values exist but if they don't then it's a 1? Can it be a mix? What happen if it's 4/1? Otherwise I say take the max and if max not in (2,4,5) then set it to 1?

Comment: @Reeza if it's 4/1, then would rank both 1. so essentially if the category is not 5/4/2, then always rank 1. Otherwise, it would be the max of (2,4,5)

Comment: Then coding anything not 2/4/5 as 99, take max and then if max is 99 reset it to 1. That’s probably what I’d do at least.